# SQLite3 — Predetermined set of values for a field?

Tags: sqlite

I'm working with SQLite3. In my schema, is it possible to require that a given field only contain values from a predetermined set?

If not, I suppose the thing to do is populate a separate table with the allowed values and then use one of the ids from that table in the field in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a check constraint:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
    MyField TEXT CHECK(MyField IN ('a', 'predetermined', 'set'))
);
```